# I am not sure php inside

Tags: php

Ya here is my code.

```
<?php print "<a href=\"http://example.com/ea.php?v=".urlencode($url)."&t=".$p."\"><?php echo $this->lang('learn_cn')?></a>" ?>
```

It comes with blank nothing show.

```
<?php echo $this->lang('learn_cn')?>
```

What is the correct way to make this work. TY

Comment: Blank => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and what does HTML source / var_dump reveal? Btw, you're already IN PHP.

Comment: Well, this is not enough information for us to help. We do not know what `$this` is in here.

Comment: Working good now. btw 3am here, can't reply u all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already in the process of `print`ing out HTML, so just escape that part like you did in the `href`:

```
<?php print "<a href=\"http://example.com/ea.php?v=" . urlencode($url) . "&t=" . $p . "\">" . $this->lang('learn_cn') . "</a>" ?>
```

Comment: 3 am here... can't handle it. Thanks.